# How to check if the user has visited all the pages of the pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

My website has a link which on clicking opens a pdf in a new tab. I would like to know if the user has visited all the pages of the pdf and upon confirmation enable a feature. How to achieve this? how to track the user`s movement on a pdf document?

Comment: Wild guess: embed the pdf in a frame and monitor the scrollbar on this frame?

Comment: I don't believe you will have access to the PDF container, even if placed in an IFrame, I've a feeling the scrollbars will be part of the PDF plugin.  But one idea, if your generating the PDF, you could maybe add a random code at the end, that your user then has to enter into your website.

Comment: Sir, I am not creating a pdf. The pdfs are uploaded by the admin for the users to view. Constraint is the user should view all the pages of the document and then only he will be able to access the feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) (by Mozilla, it's the Firefox PDF viewer) to create you own PDF viewer.

Check the [examples](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/), you will get promises when rendering pages, so you can get all stats you want from the file or pages:

```
pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
  // you can now use *page* here
});
```

Comment: Sir, What about a standard plugin? which  will work on all browsers?

Comment: It's not supported by only Firefox, it is the default PDF viewer of Firefox. The supported browsers are listed here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support